# Publishing app problem in google play console

Tags: android-studio, google-play-console

I deploy an app to play store console but the app was rejected due to privacy policy concern, So I update the app with privacy policy link in App content in the play console account also update the app bundle with privacy policy and then create a new release and upload by clicking on 'Rollout to Production'.
I want to know that-
Should I do anything else to tell google that I update the app and also provide a privacy policy link in the app content or google automatically review my app again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've added the privacy policy link in the play console and submitted the app for review in the production track, your app will be reviewed. You don't have to do anything else.